# How to create custom Azure AD roles

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I believe all Azure AD build in roles are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-developer).

How can I create a 'custom role' from "Application Developer" Azure AD role? so that, 'person/group/service principle' having this custom role can only create other service principles. That is, having only "Create service principals" permission.

Also, considering this is Azure AD role, I would like to know: The person/group/service principle having this role, can they have access to the whole tenant level? Can this somehow restricted to a particular subscription level?

Comment: What is it about the built-in Application Developer role that doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: 1st of all I'm trying to find an Azure role ( not Azure AD role) to give so that people can Create service principals to read key vault details from a particular subscription - unable to find it - is it possible? 2ndly, the requirement is only to create service principle but the build-in role give couple of more permission which I think not required.

Comment: Service Principal (SP) is an Azure AD artifact thus in order to create a SP, the user should have appropriate role in Azure AD. Once an SP is created, then a user with proper Azure RBAC role can grant access to a Key Vault in a particular Subscription.